# JavaScript function not working onsecond iteration

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JavaScript function that goes through all the HTML select boxes and makes a list of the numbers between 1 and 11 that have not been selected:

```
function onSelected(oSelected)
        {
            var sel1 = document.getElementById('preferenceSelect_0')
            var sel2 = document.getElementById('preferenceSelect_1')
            var sel3 = document.getElementById('preferenceSelect_2')
            var sel4 = document.getElementById('preferenceSelect_3')
            var sel5 = document.getElementById('preferenceSelect_4')
            var sel6 = document.getElementById('preferenceSelect_5')
            var sel7 = document.getElementById('preferenceSelect_6')
            var sel8 = document.getElementById('preferenceSelect_7')
            var sel9 = document.getElementById('preferenceSelect_8')
            var sel10 = document.getElementById('preferenceSelect_9')
            var sel11 = document.getElementById('preferenceSelect_10')  

            var SelectorArray = new Array();

            SelectorArray.push('');

            for(var ii=1; ii<12;  ii++)
            {
                if( sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex ].text != ii && 
                    sel2.options[sel2.selectedIndex ].text != ii && 
                    sel3.options[sel3.selectedIndex ].text != ii && 
                    sel4.options[sel4.selectedIndex ].text != ii && 
                    sel5.options[sel5.selectedIndex ].text != ii && 
                    sel6.options[sel6.selectedIndex ].text != ii && 
                    sel7.options[sel7.selectedIndex ].text != ii && 
                    sel8.options[sel8.selectedIndex ].text != ii && 
                    sel9.options[sel9.selectedIndex ].text != ii && 
                    sel10.options[sel10.selectedIndex ].text != ii && 
                    sel11.options[sel1.selectedIndex ].text)
                {
                    SelectorArray.push(ii);
                }               
            }

            RemoveSected(sel1, SelectorArray);
            RemoveSected(sel2, SelectorArray);
            RemoveSected(sel3, SelectorArray);
            RemoveSected(sel4, SelectorArray);
            RemoveSected(sel5, SelectorArray);
            RemoveSected(sel6, SelectorArray);
            RemoveSected(sel7, SelectorArray);
            RemoveSected(sel8, SelectorArray);
            RemoveSected(sel9, SelectorArray);
            RemoveSected(sel10,SelectorArray);
            RemoveSected(sel11,SelectorArray);                          
        }
```

This method is fired every time an option is selected in any of the select boxes.

The first time this method is fired it works fine, but the second time it is called it gives the following error:

'Unable to get property 'text' of undefined or null reference'

and it relates to the for loop starting:

```
if( sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex ].text != ii &&
```

I have 2 questions:

Why should it work the first time but not the second, and how can I fix it.

I have searched for a way to check if a select box has been selected, but none of them work. I just do not see how this could work once but not a second time, it does not make sense to me as nothing should be different??

Comment: Do `console.log(sel1, sel1.selectedIndex)` before loop and see if results are the same. Maybe you change something in DOM?

Comment: can you provide `RemoveSected`? also if you can provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with sample will be great